# Issues with appending on to csv file with Python csv writer

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to append on a row of 3 data points to an existing csv file.

```
import time
import csv
data = [[time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"), 10, 122]]

with open('C:\myfile.csv', 'a') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

The data comes out like this:

```
1   0   /   1   9   /   2   0   1   5
<blank row>                             
10/19/2015  10  122                         
<blank row>                             
10/19/2015  10  122
```

The original CSV file looked like this:

```
10/17/2015  120  22
10/18/2015  110  2
```

Expected to just add this:

```
10/19/2015  10  122
```

Comment: What did your file *start* with?  What did you expect the result to be?

Comment: @ScottHunter. I expected to only append on data. Updated my answer to reflect that. I am pretty new to Python and started with `with` as that is how all the csv examples I found started. I don't fully understand the code behind it.

Comment: What did your file *start* with?  What did you expect the file to be (not how it *changed*) after your code ran?

Comment: @ScottHunter. Sorry misread your question. Updated my OP.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. The blank lines are solved by adding `newline=''` to the `open` call, but I can't reproduce the weird spacing in the added line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import time
import csv
data = [[time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"), 10, 122]]

with open('C:\myfile.csv', 'a', newline = '') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Comment: @user2242044 just add the newline = ''